# Sequelize Slow Performance With AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, amazon-rds

Hello Guys we are using Nest JS as our backend microservice framework and are using sequelize as our ORM.

We have deployed our Microservices on AWS ECS, and are using an EC2 instance to deploy the containers.

For Microservices we have made the deployments elastic each container has 8Gb Of Ram and 4 vCPUs. And upto maximum of 3 containers can run at any given time to reduce costing.

For database we are using RDS on AWS with one write and one read instance we are using `db.t3.medium` as our database hosting instance.

For Connection we are making pools with maximum connection of about `50`.

We are estimated to get `5000 concurrent users`.

To ensure that there is no battle neck in our configuration We decided to test the configuration by placing 1000 concurrent requests to our api, in order to simulate 1000 users landing on our home page and fetching information.

The Expected behavior was that we would see some lag spike in our performance but as more containers are spun up the performance would improve.

But what is happening is that even if we have just a simple select query, of `SELECT 1;` The more the request the server gets the more the response time increases.

Initially it starts with sub `0.5 second` response but as the number of request increases the response time baloons upto `30 seconds`.

So I was wondering where the battle neck potentially could be either on

I.   Database level

II.  ORM Level

III. Application level

Comment: There are little to no details about the code/architecture/components, a complex situation that's difficult to reproduce without the code, and a performance optimization task that sounds more like a consulting gig than something for this Q&A format. Vote to close as needs more focus.

Comment: Make an API end point that just does 'select 42;'.  Is that still slow?

Comment: "When I stress test my application and send 1000 requests in parallels"  Why?  Is this how you expect to use your app?

Comment: @jjanes yes even with just a simple select query it slows down.

Comment: I was doing parallel request to some what simulate 1000 concurrent users on our front end.

Comment: @Maurice Let me rephrase.

Comment: What if you make an API even simpler yet, that just returns a string/number hard coded into the app server and never even attempts to talk to the DB?